# Add data without primary keys to a table with csvloader [voltdb]

Tags: voltdb

I want to upload data without primary keys to the database with csvloader.

```
csvloader SalesChannels -f data/SalesChannels.csv -skip 1 -r ./logs --update
```

When I do this, I get the following error message.

```
The number of failed rows exceeds the configured maximum failed rows: 100
Read 0 rows from file and successfully inserted 0 rows (final)
Elapsed time: 0.25 seconds
Invalid row file: ./logs/csvloader_SALESCHANNELS_insert_invalidrows.csv
Log file: ./logs/csvloader_SALESCHANNELS_insert_log.log
Report file: ./logs/csvloader_SALESCHANNELS_insert_report.log
```

Logs:

```
Invalid input on line 2. Incorrect number of columns. 1 found, 2 expected. Please check the table schema and the line content
  Content: Online
```

In the documentation about csvloader it says about the update flag the following:

> --update
>
> ```
> Specifies that existing records with a matching primary key are updated, rather than being rejected. By default, csvloader attempts to
> ```
>
> create new records. The --update flag lets you load updates to
> existing records — and create new records where the primary key does
> not already exist. To use --update, the table must have a primary key.

But the primary key is not creating for new records.

How can I add data without primary keys?